# array_merge function doesn't work properly in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project i'm split an array index value based on `regex` value. but when i want merge all array together the merge function doesn't merge.

Here is my code sample.

```
 $testarray=array();

    $merge_array=array();
    //receive parameter is Admin|Manager,User@Test
    foreach ($roles as $value) {
        if(preg_match("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value))
        {
            $testarray=preg_split("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value);

        }

        print_r(array_merge($merge_array,$testarray));
    }
```

The print_r show this result.

> Array ( [0] => Admin [1] => Manager ) Array ( [0] => User [1] => Test )

Comment: Can you extract a [mcve]? BTW: It would help if you formatted your code according to PSR conventions, it makes it easier for others to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just merge arrays, but don't assign results to any variable, proper code is:

```
//receive parameter is Admin|Manager,User@Test
foreach ($roles as $value) {
    if(preg_match("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value))
    {
        $testarray=preg_split("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value);
    }

    // here you add $testarray values to 
    // `$merge_array` on each iteration
    $merge_array = array_merge($merge_array,$testarray);
}
// print result array after loop
print_r($merge_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Laravel framework has nothing to do with your issue. You're using PHP's standard functions.

The array_merge function doesn't modify the array you provide to it but provides the resulting array as its output. So you should assign array_merge's result to $merge_array.

Please try the following code:

```
$testarray = array();

$merge_array = array();
//receive parameter is Admin|Manager,User@Test
foreach ($roles as $value) {
    if(preg_match("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value))
    {
        $testarray = preg_split("/[@#%$|:\s,]+/",$value);

    }

    $merge_array = array_merge($merge_array, $testarray);
}
print_r($merge_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think wrong.
`print_r(array_merge($merge_array,$testarray));`
The above line is in "foreach" loop.
In that case, to get a merged result, you should do like the followings;
`$merge_array = array_merge($merge_array,$testarray)`

In your code, $merge_array remains empty, so you see the current result.